# Is it possible to create invoice line items with an auto lookup tax type using the Xero accounting API?

Tags: invoice, xero-api

I have an Item set up with Tax rate: Auto Look Up

But when I create in invoice via the API containing line item with this item code, the tax is not looked up.

I've tried retrieving my Items from the Items API, to see its TaxType. It is set to "AVALARA".

I've tried overriding the TaxType on my line item to AVALARA. This **is** accepted by the API, but invoice does not appear to show the looked-up rate.

Answer (score 0):

he Avalara tax rate look up feature does not work for transactions imported through the API. A different rate should be used.